# First and last regex match

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

Hi I have a problem with my program, I have wrote the code below and it returns the expected result. However I only am intrested in the first and last occurance of the matches. How would I go about doing this?

```
foreach (@array)
{
    $element = $_;
    foreach(@array2)
    {
        if($_ =~ s/($element)//ig)
        {
            print "$_ \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the loop goes through every element in the array finds it in the second array and prints the whole line. It returns the expected result, however I want the first match and last match.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you please explain exactly what you're trying to do instead of how you're trying to do it? There may be a better approach than using nested loops.

Comment: Put the matches in a list instead of printing them. Then after the loop, print the first and last list elements.

Comment: You are using a substitution that *removg* any matches found, and I wonder if you realise that this can affect what strings match later on. For instance, if `@array` contains `('abc', 'def')`, and one element of `@array2` is `dabcef` then the first pass will say that `abc` has been found *but change the element from `dabcef` to `def`*. So the next pass will say that `def` also matches, which wasn't true before the modification. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could maybe do this

```
foreach (@array)
{
    $first = "";
    $last = "";
    $element = $_;
    foreach(@array2)
    {
        if($_ =~ s/($element)//ig)
        {
            if (!length($first)){
                $first = $_;
            }
            else {
                $last = $_;
            }
        }
    }
    if (length($first) && length($last)) {
        print "\n----------\nfirst = '$first'\nlast = '$last'";
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed a parenthesis on the "if (!length($first){" line - close bracket. Apart from that your idea worked like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $elm2 (@array2) {
     my $state = 'start';
     my $first, $last;

     foreach my $elm1(@array1) {
           if (($state eq 'start') && ($elm1 =~ m/$elm2/i)) {
               $first =  "$elm1";
               $state = 'last';
           }
           elsif (($state eq 'last') && ($elm1 =~ m/$elm2/i)) {
               $last = $elm1;
           }
     }
     print "$elm2,$first,$last\n";
}
```

Comment: If there is only one match, this would print it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Totally forgot about grep.

```
foreach my $elm2 (@array2) {
      my @matches = grep(/$elm2/i, @array1);
      if (@matches && (scalar (@matches > 1))) {
         print "$elm2,$matches[0], $matches[-1]\n";
      }
      elsif (@matches) {
         print "$elm2,$matches[0]\n";
      }
      else {print "no matches\n";};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but this is what I think you could use

Find first match

```
if ($_ =~ m/($element)/) { print $1; }
```

Find last match

```
if ($_ =~ m/.*($element)/) { print $1; }
```

Comment: of course if there is only 1 match, the pattern will be printed twice

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to check which elements of `@array2` match any of the patterns in `@array` and print the first and last of those,  it is simplest to build an alternation regex from the contents of `@array` and filter `@array2` using that.

Like this

```
my $re = join '|', @array; # Build a regex
$re = qr/$re/;             # Compile it

my @matches = grep /$re/, @array2;
print "$_\n" for @matches[0,-1];
```